# Force Download MP3 with PHP

Tags: php, download, mp3

Be honest : I found the way to donwload mp3 files from s******d but Im not able to donwload the MP3 directly all the music is streaming in the browser.

I already try with someting like this

```
<a href="direct_download.php?file=fineline.mp3">Download the mp3</a>
```

but my donwload link is not .mp3, this is my line of code to donwload a file

```
href="<?php echo $val['stream_url']?>?client_id=67739332564a7130c3a05f90f2d02d2e">Descargar</a>.
```

When I use the the option

```
direct_download.php?file=
```

just donwload one file with the name

```
client_id=05b4f2000dad27aa9fc48d08915d7830.html
```

The complete php code that I use is

```
<?php
$file = $_GET['file'];
header ("Content-type: octet/stream");
header ("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=".$file.";");
header("Content-Length: ".filesize($file));
readfile($file);
exit;
?>
```

Which can be accessed in any anchor like this:

```
<a href="direct_download.php?file=fineline.mp3">Download the mp3</a>
```

Could you please help me, or if you have a better ide, thank you guys

Comment: You're leaving yourself open to a [Local File Inclusion](http://hakipedia.com/index.php/Local_File_Inclusion) vulnerability.

Comment: You're just allowing any file to be downloaded... I could simply do `direct_download.php?file=../etc/passwd` and you'd be in a lot of trouble.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

if you are using html5 you can use download option

```
<a href="url_to_your_file.mp3" download>Download the mp3</a>
```

otherwise, you can use javascript

```
function saveAs(url) {    
  var filename = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf("/") + 1).split("?")[0];
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.responseType = 'blob';
  xhr.onload = function() {
    var a = document.createElement('a');
    a.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(xhr.response);
    a.download = filename; 
    a.style.display = 'none';
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.click();
    delete a;
  };
  xhr.open('GET', url);
  xhr.send();
}
```

Call it from your link

```
<a href="javascript:" onclick="saveAs(url_to_your_file.mp3)">Download the mp3</a>
```

Comment: Isaac You're A God-Damned Genius!! the javascript work perfet

Comment: You deserve that upvote. The HTML5 one is so damn clean. I am impressed, Sir.